# How to get access token using angular-oauth2-oidc for PKCE code authentication?

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, pkce, angular-oauth2-oidc

I am using angular-oauth2-oidc for authentication and I dont know how to get access token. I am using PKCE code flow with this configuraion

```
  authConfig: AuthConfig = {
    issuer: 'https://test.com/oauth/token',
    // requireHttps: false,
    redirectUri:'http://localhost:4200/',
    strictDiscoveryDocumentValidation: false,
    tokenEndpoint: 'https://test.com/oauth/token',
    clientId: 'test',
    // dummyClientSecret: 'test',
    scope: 'openid',
    oidc: true,
    responseType: 'code',
    showDebugInformation: true,
    requestAccessToken: true
  };
```

Flow is initiated with this code and after login it's redirected but I can't get any tokens.

```
  getAutherizationCodeWithPKCE() {
    this.oauthService.configure(this.authConfig);
    this.oauthService.initCodeFlow();
    this.oauthService.loadDiscoveryDocumentAndTryLogin
}
```

Comment: Check this [sample project](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards) referenced from the angular-oauth2-oidc github and its [auth.service.ts](https://github.com/jeroenheijmans/sample-angular-oauth2-oidc-with-auth-guards/blob/master/src/app/core/auth.service.ts).

Comment: this is the older project and I am using PKCE flow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Issue is resolved with sending client secret in the example above

```
   dummyClientSecret: 'test',
```

I am using Cloud Foundry authorization server that seems to require client secret.
Access token then can be easily obtained with

```
this.oauthService.getAccessToken()
```

versions:

```
angular 13.1.2
angular-oauth2-oidc 13.0.1
cloud foundry uaa 75.11.0
```

I am not deleting this question in case someone get same issue in the future.